# tsx-loader error during hooking tsx with vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js, tsx

I'm trying to hook TSX with Vuejs following some blog posts but always get the error at the bottom. I cloned a starter kit from github and worked me, so I suppose that there is a problem with my package versions. I use the default vue-cli template that gives me

"vue-loader": "^13.3.0" and "webpack": "^3.6.0"

Have you met with this error?

```
* !!tsx-loader!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./App.vue in ./src/App.vue
```

Answer (score 0):

Add babel runtime plugin 
Here is a seed project I created https://github.com/IsraelZablianov/vue-vuex-typescript-webpack-seed 
You can see the webpack config there